# Connect from a cisco device to http server on debian

Tags: python, cisco, debian-stretch

I'm trying to communicate with a http server which is running on debian strech from a brand new out of the box cisco device. Now, the so called zero touch configuration is no problem:

- The Switch gets an IP address and such via DHCP and a link to where to fetch it's initial configuration.
- The switch gets its basic configuration such as user credentials etc.
  The problem rises when I try to search through a database on the server from the switch. In this database some variables are stored. Depending the serialnumber of the switch, it should receive a specific hostname, Mgmt address etc.

On those new switches there is a python module integrated so I ran some tests. I tried to fetch the serial number and got them whithout any problems. The moment I tried to write the serial number on a txt file on the server I got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'http://10.232.152.19:80/temp.txt'

Code so far:

```
from cli import cli
def get_serial():
    serial = cli("show version | include System Serial\n")
    serial = (serial.split()[-1])
    f = open ("http://10.232.152.19:80/temp.txt", "a")
    f.write(serial)
    f.close
    get_serial()
```

Comment: you need to cache your ip @

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because you are trying to open a file from the network. You need to download the file first in you system and then open it. You should use `urllib` to fetch the file and then open it. then save it and again push it back.

```
import urllib
txt = urllib.urlopen(target_url).read()
```

Comment: with the target url "http://10.232.152.19/var/www/html/temp.txt" I get a "network unreachable" and with target url ""http:\\10.232.152.19:80\temp.txt"" I get a  "no host given", same result with the complete path or abbreviated path. (sidenote: it is reachable via a webbrowser on my local machine)